# MySQL ORDER BY not sorting properly

Tags: mysql

I have this mySQL Query

```
SELECT list.*, brand.displayed_text AS brandName
FROM itemmaster_list AS list
LEFT JOIN brand_lists AS brand ON brand.cid = list.brandcode
WHERE brandcode = 'abc'
ORDER BY list.orderpriority DESC, list.date_added DESC , list.cid DESC
```

When you run this in PHPMySQL it returns data CORRECTLY sorted by the field `[list.orderpriority]`

but when you run it in my php code (thru browser) it sorts data by the field `[list.date_added]`

PHP Code

```
$result_item = mysql_query("SELECT list.*, brand.displayed_text AS brandName FROM itemmaster_list 
AS list LEFT JOIN brand_lists AS brand ON brand.cid = list.brandcode WHERE brandcode = 'abc' 
ORDER BY list.orderpriority DESC, list.date_added DESC , list.cid DESC") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result_item) > 0) {
    while($row_item = mysql_fetch_array($result_item)) {
        [echo here the records]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you supply your PHP code?

Comment: You are missing a closing `"` on your SQL query for starters...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

It turns out our host transfer us to a new server without telling us, so we have two databases, the PHP file is connected to the new one and the phpMySQL Im playing with is the old database, thats why Im getting a different results.